# WSO2 API Manager does not work https endpoint

Tags: api, ssl, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I create an API where I configure the endpoint: https://ssl.croinform.ru:450/api.test And there is a problem with https, I am not getting a response to the request. It seems the WSO2 API Manager API gateway is not proxying requests to the endpoint. When I make requests directly, I pre-configure the infrastructure: install the openssl counterpart, install the cacer.p7b and ssl.croinform.cer certificates. After that, I successfully receive responses from the ssl.croinform.ru:450/api.test service.
I was advised to add a certificate according to this manual: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/design-api/endpoints/certificates/#adding-a-certificate-for-an-endpoint I did everything according to the manual, but requests to https are still not transmitted. The problem is I need to import two certificates: cacer.p7b, ssl.croinform.cer. I manage to add the .cer certificate, but the .p7b certificate is not added (I get an error), I suppose the .p7b file extension is simply not supported. But I need to transfer the whole certificate chain. Also, I do not understand how encryption is supported in wso2-am, but this is important, since traffic with a remote API is encrypted using tls. Am I getting it right that wso2-am works with openssl? If so, is it possible to use any other alternative software? In my case, openssl does not support some regional standards. I am still asking for hints or directions on my problem.

When I install a certificate with a .p7b extension in the portal I get the following error: The server encountered an internal error. Please contact administrator. The wso2carbon.log file contains the following events: ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.CertificateMgtUtils} - Error loading certificate. java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: Short read of DER length at java.base / sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.  (X509CertImpl.java:197) at java.base / sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate (X509Factory.java:10
Continuing: ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.certificatemgt.CertificateManagerImpl} - Error adding the certificate to Publisher Trust Store. Rolling back... ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl} - Adding certificate to the Publisher node is failed. No certificate changes will be affected. ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.EndpointCertificatesApiServiceImpl} - Error while adding the certificate due to an internal server error

Can you tell me what I need to do to make this work in WSO2 API Manager?

Comment: Can you provide the error? Because that is the guide you should be following.

Comment: When I install a certificate with a .p7b extension in the portal I get the following error:
The server encountered an internal error. Please contact administrator. The wso2carbon.log file contains the following events:
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.CertificateMgtUtils} - Error loading certificate. java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: Short read of DER length
at java.base / sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl. <init> (X509CertImpl.java:197)
at java.base / sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate (X509Factory.java:10

Comment: Continuing:
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.certificatemgt.CertificateManagerImpl} - Error adding the certificate to Publisher Trust Store. Rolling back...
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl} - Adding certificate to the Publisher node is failed. No certificate changes will be affected.
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.EndpointCertificatesApiServiceImpl} - Error while adding the certificate due to an internal server error